# How can I approach "a:hover style" Heisenbug when the obvious approach makes the hover vanish?

Tags: google-chrome, debugging, hover

I've run into a similar issue repeatedly, where I cannot usefully retain [Heisenbug behaviours](http://www.catb.org/jargon/html/H/heisenbug.html).

I can move the mouse to get a:hover (or like functionality), but moving the mouse to Chrome's debugger area eliminates the hover effect.

There are always breakpoints and console.log()—meaning I don't know what a good, modern, preferred solution would be.

Any comments on pinning down Heisenbugs with or without Chrome?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inspect the element in Chrome's developer tools.
Click the pushpin icon in the Styles tab then select the :hover checkbox.